# Java backtracking program for N queen: a StackOverFlow error

Tags: java, python, algorithm, n-queens

I am currently taking an online course that teaches various programming puzzles. This week's puzzle was N-Queen problem, and the presented code was written in Python. It is the following:

python

```
def can_be_extended_to_solution(perm):
    i = len(perm) - 1
    for j in range(i):
        if i - j == abs(perm[i] - perm[j]):
            return False
    return True

def extend(perm, n):
    if len(perm) == n:
        print(perm)
        exit()

    for k in range(n):
        if k not in perm:
            perm.append(k)

        if can_be_extended_to_solution(perm):
            extend(perm, n)

        perm.pop()

extend(perm = [], n = 25)
```

Since I am very new to programming and the only language I know a bit is Java, I re-wrote the entire code in Java to practice. However, the re-written code caused a StackOverFlow error when it was executed. It is the following:

java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please insert N in a N x N chessboard");
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    ArrayList<Integer> perm = new ArrayList<>();
    extend(perm, n);
    scanner.close();
}

public static boolean can_be_extended_to_solution(ArrayList<Integer> perm) {
    int i = perm.size() - 1;
    int[] range = new int[i];
    for (int k = 0; k < range.length; k++) {
        range[k] = k;
    }
    for (int j : range) {
        if (i - j == Math.abs(perm.get(i) - perm.get(j))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static void extend(ArrayList<Integer> perm, int n) {

    if (perm.size() == n) {
        for(int i = 0; i < perm.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(perm.get(i));
            return;
        }
    }

    int[] range = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
        range[i] = i;
    }

    for (int k : range) {
        if (perm.contains(k)) {
        }
        else {
            perm.add(k);
        }
        if (can_be_extended_to_solution(perm)) {
            extend(perm, n);
        }
        perm.remove(perm.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

}

And this is the error message in the Eclipse console:

```
Please insert N in a N x N chessboard
7
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.Integer.equals(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.indexOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.contains(Unknown Source)
    at test.extend(test.java:51) // if (perm.contains(k)) {
    at test.extend(test.java:57) // extend(perm, n);
    at test.extend(test.java:57)
    at test.extend(test.java:57)
    at test.extend(test.java:57)
    at test.extend(test.java:57)
    at test.extend(test.java:57)
```

The two codes seem similar to me, and I don't understand why my Java code is causing a StackOverFlow error while the Python code is facing no problem at all.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong in my code?

Comment: Hi Eunyoung, welcome to SO. One difference I see is that in python, on finding the solution you are exiting the complete code (exit()) whereas in Java you are just returning. Try replacing *return* with *System.exit(0)* at the start of extend function inside the if condition. The reason you are getting a SO error is because in case you return from the function, you are still inside the loop of the previous function (one level up) which will still continue to iterate and make other function calls.

Comment: Thank you for the kind comment, @Bhavin. I replaced the return statement with System.exit(0) as you suggested, but it still gives me a SO error. I added the printed error message in the original question, and I would be really grateful if you took a look at it.

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.   
You say "the two codes seem similar to me" -- on what do you base this?  Where is your attempt to trace the execution of the failing code, if not both?  We do expect you to make a good-faith attempt to debug your problem before posting; share that attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the bug is in both forms of the code.  Change the Python to this:

```
def can_be_extended_to_solution(perm):
    i = len(perm) - 1
    for j in range(i):
        if i - j == abs(perm[i] - perm[j]):
            return False
    return True

def extend(perm, n):
    if len(perm) == n:
        print(perm)
        exit()

    for k in range(n):
        if k not in perm:
            perm.append(k)

            if can_be_extended_to_solution(perm):
                extend(perm, n)

            perm.pop()

extend(perm = [], n = 25)
```

What was going wrong is that you'd see that some `k` can be added, then call `extend`  You'd come back in, try to add `k`, find it was there, find that `perm` still could be extended, and call `extend again.  Which would happen in a loop, and you then get infinite recursion.

With the new version, you only recurse when you've added something to `perm`.